# lein repl fails: "No such var user/help"

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I experience the following error:

```
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: No such var: user/help, compiling:(/private/var/folders/xy/8l2mmnsj0gv3myj72y0s2kmr0000gn/T/form-init6632573911186472967.clj:1:10884)
#<Namespace user>
Error loading namespace; falling back to user
```

This only happens in this one project. The project happily compiles to uberjar, and `lein run` works just fine, it's only the repl that doesn't work.

Anyone have any idea what this could be about?

The entire project is available at https://github.com/Skinney/coc-helper

Comment: Paste your project.clj. You maybe specifying a different namespace for the repl

Comment: Added a link to the project (open-source)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I stumbled upon this question because I had the same problem. I have opened an issue for that problem, with minimal reproducing project and workaround, on the [Leiningen github project](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/1641).

Since the OP has apparently already solved the problem, here is the TL;DR for anyone else arriving here: the problem is that you require `:as user` in the main namespace. Changing the alias solves the problem, as the OP has done in [this commit](https://github.com/Skinney/coc-helper/commit/730c946ea088d416a997082f1dc859bde9b6effc).

Comment: I completely forgot about this thread. You are entirely right, and this has already been fixed.

Comment: Can you please paste the code snippet - unfortunatelly github project is not available :(

Comment: I'm not sure what more I can say than what is in the answer here. There are more details in the linked Leiningen issue, but the gist of it is you need to change your `require` line to say `[... :as not-user]` instead of `[... :as user]`.